# How to test two parameters to be numbers with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I got a function which receives two numbers (integer), returning an array with the firsts (numbers) multiple of (value) like countBy(value, number).

e.g.

`countBy(1, 10) returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

`countyBy(2, 5) returns [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`

So, what matcher should be used to test if the function receives only numbers (integer) ?
I did a lot of tests but still did not find a solution.

```
it ('Verify if are received and returned only numbers', () => {
  expect(typeof countBy(2, 5)).toBe('number'); 
});
```

Does anybody can give me a light?

Comment: That doesn't make sense - the function isn't in control of what it _receives_, that's up to the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
const targetArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10];

test("Verify if are received and returned only numbers", () => {
  targetArray.forEach((target) => {
    expect(typeof target).toBe("number");
  });
});
```

Comment: Actually did not pass! When I type a string in the function, does not return an error as should be.

Comment: @KelsonBatista need go full array then check each element type. I have changed the code. I check my PC. it should work now.

Comment: Now it's working @MohammadAliRony! Thank you so much!